# Can MS Outlook work with iCloud? Can I iCloud-sync my iPad 2, iPhone 4S and Outlook 2010?

Tags: ipad, icloud, iphone, ms-office

I haven't been successful getting iCloud to work with Outlook 2010 on my Windows 7 PC. My iPad 2 and iPhone 4S are iCloud synced. Is it hopeless to get all 3 together: iPhone, iPad and Outlook 2010?
I get into iCloud on the PC, start the sync with Contacts and it fails. 
Should I just give up on PC/iCloud and just use iCloud for the 4S and iPad?

Comment: Did you try these solutions and did they work out for you? I need to do something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set this up by using [these instructions](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html). You need to make sure you have the [iCloud Control Panel for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). I've set this up on numerous occasions and it's worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Matt's right, you need the Control Panel for Windows, but it's also worth adding [CodeTwo Sync for iCloud](http://www.codetwo.com/sync-for-icloud/?sts=2219) to it. The Control Panel adds an additional account to Outlook and CodeTwo puts it all together by syncing the default profile with iCloud in real time.